# SED find and replace by keeping indentation

Tags: find, sed, indentation, replacement

I can't seem to find an answer, I am trying to find and replace a text.

For example, find `newName:` and replace it with a variable that expands.
I tried:

```
sed -i "/  newTag:/c  newTag: $IMAGE_TAG"
```

This one removes indentation and adds double quotes to the value (which I don't want). I only want **2** indentations before the key `NewName`, and it's value, like `NewName:  newvalue`

This below is a YAML format of a list of images:

```yaml
images:
    name: alpine/docker
    newName: replaceme
    newTag: replaceme
```

Answer (score 0):

The `s` or `substitute` command of `sed` can replace a value in a line and leave everything else intact. It can also expand Bash variables in the substitution.

```sh
newtag="NEWTAG"
echo "    oldTag: value" | sed  "s/oldTag:/$newtag:/"
```

outputs:

```
    NEWTAG: value
```

More on `s` on the [SED Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html).